# Why does for/list run here when a normal for loop doesn't?

Tags: scheme, racket

When I run this code nothing happens:

```
#lang slideshow
(define (execute-n-times f n)
  (for ([i n])
    f))
(execute-n-times (circle 20) 4)
```

However if I run the exact same thing with for/list it outputs a list of four printed circles:

```
#lang slideshow
(define (execute-n-times f n)
  (for/list ([i n])
  f))
(execute-n-times (circle 20) 4)
```

Why is the first snippet not running? How do I get it to output the four circles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` is a special form where the body gets executed for each iteration for it's side effect but the results are **never** kept. An example of side effect might be printing, storing to file or mutating data structure.

`for/list` is a special form that does the same as `for` except every result is accumulated onto a result `list`. `for/vector` does the same but you get the result of each iteration in a vector (also caled array in other languages).

The names in your code are confusing. `execute-n-times` doesn't execute anything but just return the value of `f` which happens to be the value of the evaluation of `(circle 20)` **executed once**.

To get it executed for each time you need `f` to be a function and your body to call that function:

```
(define (execute-n-times f n)
  (for/list ([i n])
    (f i)))

(execute-n-times (lambda (n) (circle (* n 10))) 4)
```

To see the difference I passed the value that changes to the function making the circles different in size each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful and well-explained answer, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are entirely correct. Let me also add this:

Try replacing `(circle 20)` with `(+ 3 4)`. Now do the results make sense?

Answer (score 0):

`for/list` accumulates the values of the evaluations of the loop body in a list. `for` does not.

Consider that the following is one way of writing `for/list` in terms of `for`:

```
#lang slideshow
(define (execute-n-times f n)
  (let ((l '()))
    (for ([i n])
      (set! l (cons f l)))
    (reverse l))
)
(execute-n-times (circle 20) 4)
```

Comment: Why does f not execute in the first case? How do I get it to print the circle 4 times without it being in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Using other [for loops](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html) may also clarify the issue:

```
(for/list ((i 5))
  i)
(for/vector ((i 5))
  i)

(for/sum ((i 5))
  i)
(for/product ((i 5))
  i)

(for/first ((i 5))
  i)
(for/last ((i 5))
  i)
```

Output:

```
'(0 1 2 3 4)        ; a list
'#(0 1 2 3 4)       ; a vector
10                  ; sum
0                   ; product
0                   ; first
4                   ; last
```

"`For`" itself produces only void:

```
(println (for ((i 5))
  i))
```

Output:

```
#<void>
```

Following is a typical usage of "`for`" :

```
(for ((i 5))
  (println i))
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```